# How do I write a transformation to support many different page types?

Tags: c#, kentico

I have a "promo" widget which wraps the built in Universal Page Viewer web part. Editors can add promo widgets to their pages in order to link to any other page in the site. The promo widget they add will render with the name of the linked page and the teaser image for that page.

The widget is configured to show the Path field so that the editor can pick the page they're promoting, and has the default value of the TransformationName field set to "CMS.MenuItem.Promo". The `TransformationName` field is marked as non-editable.

I'd really like the editor to be able to point their promo widget at any page in the site and not have to worry about what type of node they're pointing to, so I'd like to make the CMS.MenuItem.Promo transformation support any page type.

My idea is to add a custom transformation method like:

```
namespace CMS.Controls
{
    public partial class CMSTransformation
    {
        public string GetTeaser()
        {
            TreeNode node = this.get_the_current_node_somehow...();
            Page page = new PageFactory().GetPage(node);
            return page.GetTeaserRelativeURL();
        }
```

Then I can just include the following in the transformation and editors don't need to care about what type of node they have:

```
<img src="<%# GetTeaser() %>" />
```

I've already got `PageFactory` setup and working (it's used by some other code) - all it does is switch on `node.ClassName` and return a new Page object:

```
public Page GetPage(TreeNode node)
{
    switch (node.ClassName)
    {
        case CMS_Event.PageType:
            return new CMS_Event(node);
        case CMS_MenuItem.PageType:
            return new CMS_MenuItem(node);
        // etc
```

e.g. CMS_MenuItem is just:

```
public class CMS_MenuItem : Page
{
    public const string TeaserField = "MenuItemTeaserImage";
    private readonly TreeNode node;
    public CMS_MenuItem(TreeNode node)
    {
        this.node = node;
    }
    public override string GetTeaserRelativeURL()
    {
        var guid = node.GetValue<Guid>(TeaserField, Guid.Empty);
        return AttachmentURLProvider.GetAttachmentUrl(guid, node.NodeAlias);
    }
```

Is it possible to get a `TreeNode` object inside a transformation method? If so I can just use my existing code to get the teaser image regardless of the type of node I have.

If it's not possible to get a `TreeNode` in the transformation method, then what's the cleanest way to get out a field regardless of the current page type?

I'm aware of the `GetNotEmpty()` and `GetColumnName()` transformation methods, but it seems pretty ugly to have to pass a list of 12 column names every time I try and get a field out.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be easier to have a specific transformation per page type. You could have a transformation with the same code e.g. Promo and have this transformation for every page type. In the settings of your widget/web part you would initialize the property via a macro. The macro would simply get the displayed page type code name. The default value for the given property could look something like:

`{%my_macro_to_get_page_type_code_name%}.promo`

I think you would also be able to get the code name via standard K# language, but I personally haven't done this. An alternative is to use a custom form control, which could be initialized however you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Boris, that sounds like it should work - but it seems like my macro isn't being called in the TransformationName field. I've added a Utils.PageType() in my CustomMacros.cs. I've attached the Visual Studio debugger to the site with a breakpoint on the macro. If I include "{%Utils.PageType()%}" on a page then that breakpoint is hit, but if I render a widget containing a transformation name of "{%Utils.PageType()%}.Promo" then the breakpoint isn't hit. So it looks like macros in the TransformationName field aren't being called?

Comment: I've also tried setting the TransformationName to "{% classname %}.Promo" and the existing CMS.Event.Promo transformation isn't called when I point the Universal Page Viewer at an event.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the macro has to be set as the default value for the given field and the field cannot be editable by the editor. Otherwise this would be a security flaw, if macros would be resolved on editor accessible fields.

Comment: I've tested this quickly with a build in macro and it seems to be resolving just fine: [link](http://imgur.com/a/qnBmh)

Comment: Hi Boris. I can confirm that the macro wasn't being called because the field was editable by the editor - but now that that's fixed I'm still having problems getting the page type of the item the repeater is transforming. "{% classname %}" just gives me the page type of the page that holds the repeater. In a custom macro "context.RelatedObject" is a PageTemplateInstance object for the page with the repeater on it, not the transformed item. DocumentContext.CurrentDocument is obviously the document containing the repeater. Is it possible to get the page type of the repeated item?

Comment: I'd recommend to create a custom macro. I am not aware of a build in macro, but you can try to check with our support guys at support@kentico.com